# C# htmlelement invoke memeber

Tags: c#

I am trying to raise the keydown and key up events for a textarea html element, I can just set the inner text to the text I want, but the website doesn't seem to acknowledge the text is in there unless I can raise those events. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post an example of the broken code? It might help us see what you're trying to do and maybe why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I dont have any broken code, I just need a pseudo example of how its done in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [jquery keyboard events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/).  This is assuming you can use jquery

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vUhjr/) is a demo with keypup:

Comment: The functions I assume would be used are RaiseEvent or InvokeMember for a htmlelement